# Removing Reminders from entire series of appointments in Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar, reminders, recurrent

I have a simple macro to remove any reminder from the selected calendar appointment:

```
Public Sub RemoveReminder()
  If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Class = 74 Then
     Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).ReminderSet = False
  Else
    MsgBox "not an appointment"
  End If
End Sub
```

This works fine when the appointment is a single occurrence, but for recurrent appointments it only changes the one selected instance, not the entire recurring series. How do I modify this code to remove ReminderSet from an entire recurring series for those types of appointments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AppointmentItem.Parent` property returns the parent `AppointmentItem` for the recurrence instances and exceptions (master). Setting up properties on the master appointment should affect the series/occurences.

You can check whether you deal with a occurence or master appointment by using the [AppointmentItem.RecurrenceState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.recurrencestate) property which returns an [OlRecurrenceState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olrecurrencestate) constant indicating the recurrence property of the specified object.

Comment: That works, thanks! I added "If oAppt.RecurrenceState > 0 Then / Set xAppt = oAppt.Parent
/ xAppt.ReminderSet = False / End If" and that does the trick.

Comment: Good. Don't forget to mark the answer.